# Can't create a list of random characters which is not repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I started learning python a week ago. I am trying to create a dictionary to replace characters. eg(`dictionary["a"] = "%"`).

I have first created a list containng all characters order wise from `ASCII 033 to 126`. Then I tried to create a list of random characters in order to match the characters from the 1st list. But it is on an infinite loop. Does it take very long or is it my code?

Here is the code:

```
def replacement():
    s=0
    while s in range(93):
        rep.append(chr(randint(33,126)))
        if(letters[s] != rep[s]):
            k=0
            for replace in rep:
                if replace == rep[s]:
                    k+=1
            if(k<2):    
                s+=1
    print(rep)

letters = []
rep = []
i=33
while i <= 126:
    letters.append(chr(i))
    i+=1
replacement()
```

Comment: @ChihebNexus I don't think the stuff from `letters = []` onwards is supposed to be inside the function.

Comment: It's unclear to me what Sid is trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes you're right. I've edited the question

Comment: @Sid, your code will be in an infinite loop because `s` will be always between `range(93)`. Better using a `for loop`.

Comment: @WillDaSilva The idea is to fill `rep` with all the chars from `chr(33)` to `chr(126)` in a random order. Sid's algorithm currently has some flaws, but even when those flaws are fixed this approach is _very_ slow.

Comment: A better approach would be to use the builtin random.shuffle()

Comment: It's cool that you thought of this way of creating a randomized list, but do you understand why it's slow? As `rep` gets longer, it takes longer and longer to scan through `rep` to check if the new char is already in it, and the odds of randomly generating a char that _isn't_ in `rep` get lower and lower. Trying to randomly select the last couple of chars takes a very long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to populate a list with chr(33) to chr(126) in a random order, a much better approach would be to use random.shuffle()

```
from random import shuffle
letters = [chr(x) for x in range(33, 127)]
shuffle(letters)
```

These three lines could replace everything you posted in your question. It's a much faster and easier to understand way of accomplishing the task as I understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @WillDaSilva

Answer (score 2):

`while s in range(93):` doesn't do what you think it does. It checks if `s` is in range 0..92 and loops as long as this condition is true; as `s` never changes its value from the initial 0, this condition never becomes false.

To iterate over a range 0..92 you should use:

```
for s in range(93):
```

Your other while loop also should be rewritten as:

```
for i in range(33,127):
    letters.append(chr(i))
```

or even better, replaced with a list comprehension:

```
letters = [chr(i) for i in range(33,127)]
```